# How to filter packets seen on unnumbered eth then dump raw filtered stream out another eth without using iptables

Tags: packet-capture, packet-sniffers, packet-injection

I can capture packets using tcpdump OK as the source eth1 port is connected to a cisco switch span port, and filter using tcpdump options (at this stage interested in DNS packets to and from a particualar IP only).   Rather than writing to a file, I want to simply dump the filtered raw (DNS) packets onto eth2 (which could be unnumbered or numbered).  The reason for this is that a 3rd party needs access to the raw data, but I need to filter non-DNS traffic (otherwise I'd just let them connect to the switch span port).
Preferably I also want to run the process continuously.   Is there an easy way to direct the tcpdump output to an unnumbered eth interface, or is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Please make clear, well formatted, specific questions.

Comment: To summarise above - I want to capture data on one (Gigabit) ethernet port, filter only DNS packets (TCP and UDP 53) then drop those DNS packets out a second ethernet port.   How can this be done in Linux (Centos6.8)?